# Makefile, using mpiCC compiler for main.cpp and g++ for other functions of the src code

Tags: c++, makefile, mpi

I have created a source code in C++ and I want to compile it by using **makefiles**. The problem is that I want my main functions to compile with **mpiCC** and the other functions to compile with **g++**. Is this possible?

What should I change in the following makefile?

Thanks in advance,

Ilias

```
.PHONY: all clean

CC=mpiCC #g++
CFLAGS=-c -O3

LOCAL_INC_PATH = ../include

SOURCES= main.cpp \
         f1.cpp \
         f2.cpp 

OBJECTS=$(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(SOURCES))

LIP = $(LOCAL_INC_PATH)

HEADERS = $(LIP)/func_all.h

all: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $^ -o MIE -I$(LOCAL_INC_PATH)

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -I$(LOCAL_INC_PATH)

clean:
    rm *.$(OBJECTS)
```

Comment: What doesn't work with your makefile? Can you show the error messages in your question please?

Comment: Makefile works, but it works with mpiCC for all of the functions. I don't want this. I want just to compile main with mpiCC and f1,f2 with g++.

Comment: Put explicit rules for `main.cpp` and the other files then.

Comment: you could also create a directory for all source files you want to compile with mpiCC and one for g++ and use a makefile for each directory that creates the respective object files. Then use a makefile in your main directory for executing the other makefiles and linking

Comment: @Ilias Sorry I got it wrong in my answer first. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

You can put an additional explicit rule for `main.cpp`:

```
# ...

CC=g++

# ...

SOURCES= f1.cpp \
         f2.cpp 

OBJECTS=$(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(SOURCES)) main.o

# ...

main.o : main.cpp
    mpiCC $(CFLAGS) $^ -I$(LOCAL_INC_PATH)

# ...
```

Comment: Shoudn't I change something in this line too:

all: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $^ -o MIE -I$(LOCAL_INC_PATH)

?

Comment: @Ilias I don't think so, unless you want to link with `mpiCC` as well.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, of course.

```
CC=g++             # compile everything with g++
main.o : CC=mpiCC  # compile main.o with mpiCC
```

The above uses [target-specific variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific). When compiling `main.o` it replaces the value of `CC` with `mpiCC`.

Please note, the convention is that `CC` variable is the C compiler, whereas `CXX` is the C++ one. Same applies to flags, `CFLAGS` vs `CXXFLAGS`.

Comment: Nice shortcut, I always forget about this.

Comment: This one gives an error because of the following line:
all: $(OBJECTS) $(CC) $^ -o MIE -I$(LOCAL_INC_PATH)

MIE is the executable file that should be created.

Comment: @Ilias Would be helpful to look at the error text, it might shed some clues. And you should have a separate rule to build `MIE`, `all` should be a phony target.

Comment: The error is something like that:

main.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x16e): undefined reference to `MPI_Init'
...
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x210): undefined reference to `MPI_Finalize'
main.o:(.rodata._ZTVN3MPI8DatatypeE[_ZTVN3MPI8DatatypeE]+0x78): undefined reference to `MPI::Datatype::Free()'
main.o:(.rodata._ZTVN3MPI3WinE[_ZTVN3MPI3WinE]+0x48): undefined reference to `MPI::Win::Free()'
collect2: 
error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:50: recipe for target 'all' failed

Comment: @Ilias That basically means that you need to **compile** and **link** `main.o` with `mpiCC`. You need a rule for `MIE` executable, it must not be `all`. See https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=mpi-apps#cant-use-wrappers